# How to make shared example with RSpec with parametrized code to test without using eval method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, dry

I have a shared example in RSpec, which tests SMS sending. In my app I have few methods which send an SMS, so I'd like to parametrize the code I test, so that I can use my shared example for all my methods. The only way to do that which I discovered is using `eval` function:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "sending an sms" do |action_code|
  it "sends an sms" do
    eval(action_code)
    expect(WebMock).to have_requested(**my_request**).with(**my_body**)
  end
end
```

So I can use this example like that:

```
it_behaves_like "sending an sms",
  "post :accept, params: { id: reservation.id }"

it_behaves_like "sending an sms",
  "post :create, params: reservation_attributes"
```

How can I achieve this without using `eval` function? I tried to use the pattern with `yield` command, but it doesn't work because of scope:

> Failure/Error: post :create, params: reservation_attributes
>     `reservation_attributes` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually in your case, action and params can be passed as arguments into shared examples:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "sending an sms" do |action, params|
  it "sends an sms" do
    post action, params: params
    expect(WebMock).to have_requested(**my_request**).with(**my_body**)
  end
end
```

And called as:

```
it_behaves_like "sending an sms", :accept, { id: reservation.id }

it_behaves_like "sending an sms", :create, reservation_attributes
```

Or you can define [separate action for every block](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples#providing-context-to-a-shared-group-using-a-block)

```
RSpec.shared_examples "sending an sms" do
  it "sends an sms" do
    action
    expect(WebMock).to have_requested(**my_request**).with(**my_body**)
  end
end

it_behaves_like "sending an sms" do
  let(:action) { post :accept, params: { id: reservation.id } }
end

it_behaves_like "sending an sms" do
  let(:action) { post :create, params: reservation_attributes }
end
```

Comment: Important warning: we shouldn't use `let!` function here (with exclamation mark), because that way our code in braces will be executed before the whole test, also before `before` block, what can be very disturbing. I just added exclamation mark to the function habitually and that was not good idea.